# How can I reset my maxlength in textarea if modal close?

Tags: razor, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5

How can I reset my textarea maxlength if I close my modal.

I already did cleaning my textarea if I close my modal but my maxlength validation is not resetting.

```
<div class="modal fade" id="Cancel" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Cancel-label" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog" style="top: 100px; width: 325px;">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="Cancel-label">Reason for Disapproval</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Reason for disapproval of the item(s). [Required]</p>
            @Html.TextArea("Remarks", new { 
                                           @placeholder= "100 characters left.",
                                           @required=true,
                                           @style="height:120px; width: 750px;",
                                           @data_bind = "textInput: message.view"
                                         })
            <br>
            <span data-bind="text: charLeft"></span> characters left.
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" name="command" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-primary col-sm-3 pull-left">OK</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-sm-3 pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have this knockoutjs which bind the maxlength

```
        ko.extenders.maxlength = function (target, maxlength) {
            var view = ko.dependentObservable({
                read: target,
                write: function (value) {
                    if (value.length <= maxlength) {
                        target(value);
                    } else {
                        view.notifySubscribers(target());
                    }
                }
            });
            target.view = view;
            target.maxlength = maxlength;
            return target;
        };

        function ViewModel() {
            this.message = ko.observable('').extend({ maxlength: 100 });
            this.charLeft = ko.pureComputed(function () {
                return this.message.maxlength - this.message().length;
            }, this);
        }

        ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

And for clearing my textarea i have this jquery

```
        $('#Cancel').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
            $(this)
              .find("input,textarea,select")
                 .val('')
                 .end()
              .find("input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]")
                 .prop("checked", "")
                 .end();
        })
```

Can someone help me.

Comment: Just a clarification, did you mean the validation to be the `charLeft` computed? If it is, then the one that needs to be cleared onclose is the value of `this.message`. Changing the value of the input text via jquery wont trigger the computed function.

Comment: yeah the `charLeft` computed,
can you show me how?

Comment: Okay i'll cook up something, will be back in a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your current solution in which you uses `hidden.bs.modal` event (which is bad if this will not be handled by a custom binding), you can achieve it by clearing `message`.

First you need to assign your `ViewModel` instance like:

```
var vm = new ViewModel();
```

And then use it in the `hidden.bs.modal` event like:

```
$('#Cancel').on('hidden.bs.modal', function(e) {
    vm.message("");
});
```

Check working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/96ztusp5/).

**BUT** this is not a good way to deal with knockout. If you don't want to use custom bindings then you can just use the `click` binding in order to clear the `message`.

Like:
Add this in your ViewModel:

```
this.clearMessage = function(){
   this.message("");
};
```

And modify your html bindings:

```
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true" data-bind="click: clearMessage">&times;</button>
.............................
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default col-sm-3 pull-left" data-dismiss="modal" data-bind="click: clearMessage">Close</button>
```

Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/96ztusp5/1/).

Comment: this is great. so you mean instead of clearing it if the modal is close by clicking outside, you did is by clearing it if it supposedly close?.

Comment: On the first solution the message will be cleared if the modal is closed in any way, on the second solution the message will be cleared if and only if the `close` or `x` button will be clicked, so closing via clicking outside the modal will not clear the message via solution number 2. And that is where custom binding will come in handy. :D there are many implemented bootstrap custom bindings out there already like this one: https://faulknercs.github.io/Knockstrap/

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you write DOM-manipulating code, ask yourself why you're not doing this in the viewmodel. Maybe you need a custom binding handler. Maybe you just need to bind more elements. Maybe you just need to work with the elements you've bound.

You're doing this backwards: you should be using `message.view` to clear the textArea, not writing to the textArea in the hopes of clearing `message.view`.